How to interpret the "As much as" in "As much as I like her, I can't agree with her on this."
How to interpret the As much as in "As much as I like her, I can't agree with her on this."
Does it convery a meaning of concession or comparison?
In other words, does the sentence mean the extent I disagree is equal to that of "I like her" or "As much as" is interchangeable with "Although"?
How could I discriminate the "as much as" in the sentence above from that in "I like her as much as she likes me"?

It's not very idiomatic in modern English to "front" the highlighted adverbial comparative element in I like her as much as she likes me. The only version that normally occurs is the "frozen form" biblical quote As you give, so shall you receive. Which is almost never "extended" to As much as you give, so shall you receive anyway. But you'd always just use logic and the full context to decide whether any given instance of the format is comparative or contrastive.

Compare:  "Nice as it is, the car is too expensive for me."

You can find both meanings in this dictionary. I won't vote to close since the "how can I discriminate" part of your question wouldn't be answered by the dictionary, but in the future, please look words up before posting. Then if you still have confusion, the question will be narrower and the answers will help you more.

No, it isn't a comparison.
The first as isn't really necessary, though that version seems to be common nowadays. I would say Much as I like her..., meaning Even though I like her a lot...

It may also be worth noting that the reason for the tag at the start of the sentence is to soften the impact of the disagreement: I can't agree with her on this, but I don't want her to interpret that disagreement as me disliking her too.

I believe that the as has become common because the whole clause is now grammatically opaque to most speakers, so they substitute a different and more familiar idom as much as..., even though it doesn't make sense grammatically. A similar example is how the clause so to speak has become so as to speak. That is how language changes.

I just added a comment to the question: this usage can be found in the dictionary, but might I suggest you address the "how can I tell the difference" part of the question?

OP asks "...how can I discriminate?" if the statement is taken as a comparative, not as a concession that although you like her a lot, you disagree with her on something.

As much as I like her, I can't agree with her on this.

We are not likely to express the degree of disagreement on a particular subject in terms of the degree of liking for the person we're disagreeing with, as that comparison is an inversion and for that reason is counterintuitive:

I disagree with her on that as much as I like her.
As much as I like her, I disagree with her on that.

if you adore her, you are vehemently opposed to her position on the subject, and if you hate her guts, you are in perfect agreement with her on the matter.

'As much as I like her, I can't agree with her on this' is no form of comparison, particularly not of the extent of their disagreement to that of liking her…
In contrast, yes ‘As much as…’ here is wholly interchangeable with ‘Although…’
Quite separately, discriminating between ‘As much as I like her, I can't agree with her on this’ and ‘I like her as much as she likes me’ sadly seems to rely more on context and knowledge of idiom, on which I stand to be corrected.
Even so, basically ‘…I can't agree with her…’ contains no element of value to be used for comparison. By contrast, ‘as much as she likes me’ consists of nothing but elements of value to be used for comparison.
Further, although ‘I like her as much as she likes me’ seems reasonable as a contrived example, it’s equally unlikely to be found in ordinary English.
Nothing greatly similar to ‘I like her as much as she likes me’ will commonly be heard in English, except where a parent is using degrees of loving to teach a very young child about comparison… and please note, many if not most of those parents would not notice that was what they were doing.
From that perspective, was ‘I like her as much as she likes me’ interesting in and of itself, or can you Post other, equally relevant examples?

Disclaimer
As was pointed out by others, it seems not to be a grammatically correct comparison or it is even rarely used in English. Its origin is therefore maybe a translation into English?
Other sources mention that there is a difference of British English ("Much as...") and American English ("As much as...") applicable here:

StackExchange on English Language - "As much as" at the beginning of a sentence
Collin's Dictionary on "As much as"
If you think AI is reliable, check ludwig.guru as kind of a corpus search on that sentence.
There were no matches to this sentence structure on Oxford Dictionary Online.

Apparently the example can only be interpreted as being like a comparison. In German for example, you find such sentences more commonly.
There is a learning video on YouTube which exactly explains the interpretation as I do understand it here.
Take the following as help to understand the meaning of the sentence, but not necessarily as confirmation to build such figures of speech, unless you do it deliberately.
Interpretation
Implicitly there are two "measures" being compared (or better: put into a relation):

The amount of how much "I like you".
The amount of how much of "I like you" is needed to "agree with you".


"[As much as] I like her [, although / but], I can't agree with her on this."

It is expressed, that the amount of "I like you" is not sufficient to also "agree" on the topic in question.
Your assumption to substitute with a simple "although" or "but" is correct. See the square brackets in the quote above.
Here are more rewrites on this sentence:

Although I like you, I can't agree with you.
I like you, although/but I can't agree with you.
As much as I like you, I don't like you enough to agree with you.
I really do like you, you know, but I am sorry, I cannot agree with you.

Discrimination to "real comparisons"
I think the best discrimination is that in a real comparison you have two positive expressions on both sides, which also refer to the same "thing" being compared, while in the example given, there is a positive and a negative/negated expression (because you do not agree) and also a "liking" is put in relation to an "agreeing".
Examples:

I like her[+] as much as she likes me[+].

Expressing a "normal" comparison and equality of the levels.
"As much as" could also be "more than" etc.
If in reality both dislike/hate each other, this will be a case of an ironic or sarcastic statement.


I like her[+] as much as she doesn't like me[-].

Expressing an equality (or imbalance rather) of opposite levels, "like" and "dis-like".
There is a "flip" (negation) in the comparison.
There is some "tragic" or "regretful" connotation to the comparison.
This is an analogue case for the initial example with "agreeing" (I
like her, but I am not agreeing). In this form it is a figure of speech, mostly used to express something like "pitty", because the levels are not zero but still do not match (they are still not high enough), although it would be nice "if" they matched.



For completeness:

I don't like her[-] as much as she does like me[+].

See 2. There is an (strong and twisted) aversion expressed in the comparison.


I don't like her[-] as much as she doesn't like me[-].

Both dislike each other the same.
Because both sides of the comparison are negated, this case can also be treated as a "real" comparison of equality, like in 1.
There is not much pitty expressed here, but it could be intended, because the negative form might have been used to emphasize something.




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I don't see the problem actually. I describe in minute detail how to understand that sentence and also how to discriminate this one from other comparisons. I think it is helpful. If not, let me know, I can also delete this answer.

This is a high-quality, high-effort answer, and your analysis is fair as a matter of interpretation. I just don't think you're correct or that this is a good way for learners to look at it. I wouldn't bother DV'ing if it didn't look so helpful and authoritative as to cause significant confusion, and if you put this much thought into more answers I'm sure you'll rack up a positive reputation in no time.

Okay, fair point. Thanks for the feedback! - I incorporated some sources to bolster the answer and also added a prominent disclaimer.

What do you think about the explanation in this video? It is no proof maybe, but it does interpret the example sentence as I do in my answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mO2FW5zfH34

The video, correctly, defines this usage completely separately from the "comparison" sense. I see you've de-emphasized the "comparison" part of your answer, which helps; rewriting it entirely would help further. I went ahead and fixed an error in one of your sentence rewrites. At this point the most misleading thing is the objectively false claim that the phrase is grammatically incorrect and/or calqued into English.
